# subprocess returncode and poll cause different result

Tags: python, subprocess

## Question

I have a doubt about `subprocess` module, `returncode` and `poll()` is related.

**Python version is 3.9.6**

1. [returncode](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode)

```
Popen.returncode
The child return code, set by poll() and wait() (and indirectly by communicate()). A None value indicates that the process hasn’t terminated yet.
```

2. [poll()](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll)

```
Popen.poll()
Check if child process has terminated. Set and return returncode attribute. Otherwise, returns None.
```

But, following code is infinite loop, if I add `print(proc.poll())` in the loop, it will work fine.

```py
import shlex
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('python3 --version'),
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while proc.returncode is None:
    # print(proc.poll())
    print(proc.stdout.readline())
```

Following code work fine.

```py
import shlex
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('python3 --version'),
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while proc.poll() is None:
    # print(proc.poll())
    print(proc.stdout.readline())
```

My question is :

**`proc.poll()` return `proc.returncode` attribute, why they work differently?**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @alec_djinn I'm sorry for not describing my problem clearly, now I edited my question

Comment: `returncode` isn't going to change on its own, you have to call `poll()` (or other specific methods) to update it.